# Read directory file in azure cloud service worker role

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-cloud-services

I am trying to read few sql files from directory in azure worker role. Here is my code,

```
string appRoot = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RoleRoot");

string pathToFiles = Path.Combine(appRoot + @"\", @"approot\SQLScript\");

if (Directory.Exists(pathToFiles))
{
}
```

I have placed few sql files under ***SQLScript*** directory with ***copy always*** option, so that it copies those file in bin directory.

Code works fine when I debug in local machine. But it's not working on azure.

This condition fails on azure,

```
if (Directory.Exists(pathToFiles)) { }
```

Comment: Your path construction looks valid. Have you RDP'd into the instance to verify that the files are where you believe they should be?

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue

%ROLEROOT%\approot\MyDirectory can be accessible by scripts that ran on startup of the Role

however if you RDP onto the VM that runs the Role you will not be able to access this path

you can try referencing the files through relative path 
depends on what you wish to do with them

hope this helps